# how to order by sub-collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I built a data structure in firestore like that:

[image: data1]

[image: data2]

How to order all documents in cities by the salary of doctor document in Job sub-collections?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) says you can't:

> Limitations: You can't easily delete subcollections, or perform compound queries across subcollections.

What I would do is create another collection called SalariesByCity or something, that contains:

- The ID of the city
- The ID of the job
- The salary

Then you could first query this collection filtering by the job and ordering by the salary (you will need to create an index for that), and then for each line you can query the City collection by ID to get the city details.

You could also include the city name in this SalariesByCity collection so you wouldn't even need to perform another query. But then you need to always update this collection whenever you update the city. [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) might be helpful for that.

So your collection could be something like this:

- The ID of the city
- The name of the city or even the city object
- The ID of the job
- The name of the job
- The salary

Comment: Thank you. I use this data structure because I want to minimize the writing operations when updating the salary.